# Runge Kutta implementation is less accurate than Euler implementation

Tags: javascript, simulation, game-engine, physics, runge-kutta

So I am trying to code a 2D Physics engine, and I am in need of a more accurate ODE solver so that my spring simulation does not become unstable. I want to make a stiff, or rigid spring that acts like a pendulum, which is simulated more accurately by make the stiffness as high as possible.

Currently, I have implemented the following RK4 method, but through testing, it appears that the Spring is more unstable and breaks at lower stiffness values compared to Euler's method:

```
const acc = this.getTotalAcc();

const k1 = acc.divide(state.preset.options.stepsPerFrame);
const k2 = acc.add(k1.divide(2)).divide(state.preset.options.stepsPerFrame);
const k3 = acc.add(k2.divide(2)).divide(state.preset.options.stepsPerFrame);
const k4 = acc.add(k3.divide(2)).divide(state.preset.options.stepsPerFrame);

const deltaVel = k1
  .add(k2.multiply(2))
  .add(k3.multiply(2))
  .add(k4)
  .divide(6);
this.vel = this.vel.add(deltaVel);

const deltaPos = this.vel.divide(state.preset.options.stepsPerFrame);
this.pos = this.pos.add(deltaPos);
```

I checked this a couple of times, and I don't believe I made any calculation mistakes, but I could be wrong.

For reference, here is my Euler's implementation:

```
this.vel = this.vel.add(acc.divide(state.preset.options.stepsPerFrame))
this.pos = this.pos.add(this.vel.divide(state.preset.options.stepsPerFrame));
```

Here is my spring interaction function in case you need to see how it works. `this.end` and `this.start` are the objects attached to each end of the spring:

```
interact() {
  const distance = this.end.pos.subtract(this.start.pos);
  const force = this.stiffness * (distance.magnitude() - this.length);

  // Distribute tensions between masses
  const startTension =
    (this.start.inverseMass /
      (this.start.inverseMass + this.end.inverseMass)) *
    force;
  const endTension =
    (this.end.inverseMass / (this.start.inverseMass + this.end.inverseMass)) *
    force;

  this.start.accs[this.name] = distance.unit().multiply(startTension);
  this.end.accs[this.name] = distance.unit().multiply(-endTension);
}
```

Comment: The RK formula doesn't seem right. To apply RK4, you have, for `k1` to evaluate the acceleration at the current `x`, which you did; then, for `k2` you have to evaluate the acceleration at `x + h*k_1/2` (that is use `x + h*k_1/2` for the position `x`); then for `k3` - get the acceleration  at `x + h * k_2/2`; and for `k4`, get the acceleration at `x + h * k_3`. I don't see where you do all those changes for the `x` argument in the evaluation of acceleration, it appears that you are adding `h*k_1/2`, etc. to the original acceleration instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The k4 computation should not have division by 2

You are using division by StepsPerFrame instead of multiplication by the step size. This needs also to apply to the final computation, after the division by 6.

You should also compute your position updates with the RK4 method. For mechanical systems that are described by second order equations, this can be integrated into the velocity computation as described in https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/34257/solving-coupled-odes-using-runge-kutta-method, general remarks in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4177218/115115

These are the structural errors regarding the parameters of the RK4 method. You have a deeper error in applying the method. It should be something like

```
k2 = getTotalAcc( vel.add(k1.divide(2).divide(stepsPerFrame)) )
```

or

```
k2 = getTotalAcc( vel.add(k1.divide(2)) ).divide(stepsPerFrame)
```

depending on if the k vectors are the derivatives or the increments (equal derivative times time step).

The derivatives are computed in every stage of the RK4 step. What you do makes no sense, try to translate the function calls back into mathematical formulas to see this.

---

Making the springs stiff literally increases the stiffness of the ODE system. You need to keep the step size small, or stepsPerFrame large enough, to remain inside the stability region of the method. This can not be directly checked, you would need to compare computation runs with different step sizes.

---

Your Euler method is semi-explicit or symplectic Euler.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation! However, I have one question, I'm not sure how I can calculate the acceleration at a certain position in the future. For the pendulum, that is okay, however, to use RK4 as a general method for re-positioning objects, it is hard to predict what acceleration an object will experience.

Comment: What you describe, resembles an implicit method. RK4 is explicit, all positions and velocities are directly computable from the previously known states, velocities and the computed accelerations.

Comment: Ok, so in this case, since the state of an object is generally unpredictable, I should generally use an implicit method. However, since the spring has a predictable acceleration at a certain position, I can use an explicit method in order to increase accuracy. Is that right?

Comment: Also, I implemented the RK4 method, and it works for a single pendulum, however, it stops working efficiently for double or more pendulums.

Comment: You might have run into stability issues. The single pendulum, like the single planet in a solar system (on a near circular orbit), are rather stable problems. The double pendulum as the 3-body system are inherently chaotic and have sharp turns. One can see this from a sampling frequency perspective or that the stiffness of the ODE system is locally very high. Both say that a fixed-step approach is sub-optimal. So explore step-doubling and embedded methods. But first, test your implementation with some easy test problems like the circle system to make sure that the error is of fourth order.